# Reverse Lotto Search has CRAZY fees (new to solidity): Gas estimation errored with the following message

Tags: solidity

I am new to solidity and for this project I am trying to do a reverse lottery drawing, where the losers are drawn and appended until only the winner remains.

I keep getting a gas estimation error:
Gas estimation errored with the following message (see below). The transaction execution will likely fail. Do you want to force sending?
gas required exceeds allowance (29970705)

I have tried upping my gas when I deploy on remix and all that does is up my cost when I run - it currently estimates 75000ethererum for running: drawLoser()

I use fulfullRandomWords which calls Chainlink VRF - which gives me a verified random seed, I then use this seed in drawLoser(). current_supply is hardcoded at 10000 for testing.  I then use my random seed to make a random number and check if that number exists in my losers array, if it does not exist, I increment and generate a new number from the same seed and repeat until I find a new number.  I am trying to do all of this without storing anything except my uint16 entry in my loser array, but I am guessing I am doing something stupid and storing more than I realize on the blockchain since the gas fee is absurd.

Thank you for any help!

```
  function fulfillRandomWords(
    uint256, /* requestId */
    uint256[] memory randomWords
  ) internal override {
    s_randomWords = randomWords;
  }

  function exists1(uint16 num) public view returns (bool) {
      for (uint i = 0; i < losers.length; i++) {
          if (losers[i] == num) {
              return true;
          }
      }
      return false;
  }

//Right now I need to fulfill randomwords and then drawLoser - draw loser does not generate a new seed
  function drawLoser() public {
    //fulfillRandomWords;
    uint16 drawing;
    uint i = 0;
    uint j = 1;
    //generate 10% of total entrys as losers
    while(i < 10*(current_supply-getCountLosers())/100) {  //current_supply is entrys in lotto
      drawing = uint16(uint256(keccak256(abi.encode(s_randomWords[0], j)))%(current_supply-losers.length)+1);
      if (exists1(drawing) == true){
        j++;
      }
      if (exists1(drawing) == false){
        losers.push(drawing);
        i++;
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

> error: Gas estimation errored with the following message (see below). The transaction execution will likely fail. Do you want to force sending? gas required exceeds allowance (29970705)

This means that your transaction is going to fail to tripped `require()` or `revert`.